# Random ouput is displayed when tranferring image data

Tags: php, image

This is my code. The user adds an image from a previous page where it is then collected by $_FILES and processed in this page. The weird thing is, when someone adds an image, I get a large random paragraph of random numbers and symbols that is displayed on this page. I have no clue where this is from. Any thoughts?

And if you guys were curious, that form at the bottom redirects all the information to another page where is then added into the database.

```
  <?php
        $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        if(isset($file))
        {
            $image_1 = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);         
        }
        if ($image_size===FALSE)
        {
            die("That is not an image. Please go back and choose and image.");
        }


  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $author = $_POST['author'];
  $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $location = $_POST['location'];
  $class = $_POST['class'];
  $description = $_POST['description'];
  $contact = $_POST['contact'];
  $img = $image_1;
  $img_name = $image_name;



  if(!$title || !$author || !$isbn || !$price || !$location || !$class || 
          !$description || !$contact)
  {
      echo "You have not entered all the required details.<br/>"
      ."Please go back and try again.";
      exit;
  }
  ?>
    <h1>This is what will be submitted</h1>


    <?php
    echo <<<_END
    <pre>
        Title: $title
        Author: $author
        ISBN: $isbn
        Price: $price
        Location: $location
        Class: $class
        Description: $description
        Contact Information: $contact
        Your Image :

            If this is correct, please press sumbit. If you would like to
            make changes, go back and make them
    </pre>
 _END;
?>

    <form action='PSBE_INSERT_AD.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $title;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="author" value="<?php echo $author;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $isbn;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $price;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?php echo $location;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="class" value="<?php echo $class;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="<?php echo $description;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="contact" value="<?php echo $contact;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?php echo $img;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image_name" value="<?php echo $img_name;?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Ad Post" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the binary source of the image here:

```
$image_1 = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

Then echoing it out in the hidden field here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?php echo $img;?>" />
```

That is most likely where that paragraph is coming from. Not sure why you are including it, the tmp path is all you really need.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick but that's strange because none of the other variables are being displayed. Would you happen to know why this is an exception?

Comment: The binary source of the image is just a bunch of letters and symbols, it most likely escaped the `value` attribute of your input and echoed out the rest of the source.

Comment: Little problem. If I do not echo $img, then the data does not transfer onto the next page

Comment: You need to use `move_uploaded_file` to the directory you want to store them in and pass that url in the form. [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)